# How to set another database for test on knexfile?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, knex.js

I have 2 databases; the first for the developement and production and the second for the test.
knexfile.js:

```
const config = require('config');

const knexConfig = config.get('knexConfig');

module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: knexConfig.client,
    connection: {
      host: knexConfig.host,
      database: knexConfig.database,
      user: knexConfig.user,
      password: knexConfig.password,
    },
    pool: {
      min: knexConfig.min,
      max: knexConfig.max,
    },
  },
  test: {
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
      filename: './file.db',
    },
  },
};
```

route.test.js:

const Model = require('objection').Model;

```
const provider = require('../../../server/models/provider');
const Knex = require('knex');
const knexConfig = require('../../../knexfile');

const knex = Knex(knexConfig.test);
Model.knex(knex);


describe('Should test provider Model', () => {
  test('should return provider', () => {
    provider
      .query()
      .then((providers) => {
        expect(providers).toBe('array');
      });
  });
});
```

I got this error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    ProcessTerminatedError: cancel after 2 retries!

      at Farm.<anonymous> (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/farm.js:87:25)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Farm.<anonymous> (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/farm.js:81:36)
      at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)

A worker process has quit unexpectedly! Most likely this is an initialization error.
```

I want to connect to sqlite database for the test but I can't do that to pass tests.How can I fix that?

Comment: Which test runner are you using? Looks like you are not waiting that async code terminates before test case is exitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config seems to be fine, since following test works.

https://runkit.com/embed/3w0umojslatc

```
require('sqlite3');
var knex = require("knex")({
  client: 'sqlite3',
  connection: {
    filename: './db.db' 
  }
})

const { Model } = require('objection');
Model.knex(knex);

await Model.query().select('1');
```

Looks like you are mixing DBB and TDD syntax and have some error of not waiting async results before returning from test.

Try first this:

```
const Model = require('objection').Model;
const provider = require('../../../server/models/provider');
const Knex = require('knex');
const knexConfig = require('../../../knexfile');

const knex = Knex(knexConfig.test);
Model.knex(knex);


describe('Should test provider Model', () => {
  it('should return provider', () => {
    return Model.query().from('providers')
      .then((providers) => {
        expect(providers).toBe('array');
      });
  });
});
```

If that works then try to do the query with your own `providers` class that you hadn't included in question